# Python FTP Upload Multiple Files at Once

Tags: python, ftp, rar

So, I have a script I'm working on to back up large a server('s directory) of files to a number of FTP accounts/services/whatever (at the moment the poor secretary has a copy-and-paste document to do this, but anyways I'm close to having a working script to save her from that =D).

I haven't really messed around with threading or multiprocessing before, but I can't figure out how to get it to take the list of files and upload 'em all to the host 3-5 at a time (in this example, I'm trying 5, but I dunno what I'll decide on).

```
import os, sys, subprocess, shutil, re, string, glob, tvdb_api, itertools, multiprocessing, ftplib

files = [os.path.join(r, f) for r, d, fs in os.walk(os.getcwd()) for f in fs if not f[0]=='.']
class FTP_Upload:
    def __init__(self, p=os.getcwd()):
        self.files_to_upload = sorted([f for f in files if os.path.split(f)[0] == p])
        self.target = raw_input("Enter the host you want to upload to: ")
        self.host = FTP('ftp.host1.com', 'user_name1', 'super_secret_password1') if self.target == 'host' else FTP('ftp.host2.com', 'user_name2', 'secret_password2') if self.target == 'host2' else None
    def upload_files(self, f):
        self.host.storbinary(('STOR /'+f.split('/')[-1]), open(f, 'rb'))
    def multiupload(self):
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
        p.map(self.upload_files(f), self.files_to_upload)
FTP_Upload().multiupload()
```

But this just uploads the last file in self.files_to_upload...

I tried just making the file list an iterable

```
self.files_to_upload = iter(sorted([f for f in files if os.path.split(f)[0] == p]))
```

But no joy.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where is the question? And you know that there is a [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib)?

Comment: Haha, sorry, I get even more ramble-y and ADD when I don't sleep.  I should take the keyboard away from myself, but I'm just never that smart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this sort of thing can be done quite easily with `multiprocessing`.  just write a function to upload one file --

e.g.

```
def upload_one(filename):
    """ This function uploads one file.  
        Perhaps is a a wrapper to your Popen call? """
```

and then use mulitprocessing on a list of files

```
mylistoffiles=[ ] #Somehow generate your list of files to be uploaded.
import multiprocessing
Pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=X)   #X is the number of processes you want to use
Pool.map(upload_one,mylistoffiles)
```

You can also play around with the chunksize which will speed things up a little bit if the uploads are quick.

Of course, if you need to pass more information than just the filename, one really easy way to accomplish that would be to make your list of files a list of tuples and unpack them in the function.

**WARNING**

Some might consider this bad practice since you're essentially using a map function for side-effects...

**EDIT**

I think your problem is `p.map(self.upload_files(f), self.files_to_upload)`
I'm not familiar with the `FTP` in python, so I can't say for sure, but you want to pass a *function* as the first parameter to `p.map`.  You're passing the output of the function -- It's possible that you wrote a function which returns a function, but it doesn't look like it from the code above.

What you probably want is:

```
p.map(self.upload_files,self.files_to_upload)
```

In general, a call to a `map` function can be translated to a list comprehension as follows:

```
map(function,iterable)
```

is almost equivalent to

```
[function(i) for i in iterable]
```

(almost equivalent because in python3.x `map` returns a generator.  Notice that in `map` you don't actually call the function.

**Final Edit** (hopefully)

You're running into an (unfortunate) limitation of `multiprocessing`.  All the objects that you send around *must be pickleable*.  Apparently your instance method (a method bound to an instance of a class) is not pickleable.  One solution is that you can to change it to being a regular function.  You can do that as follows.

```
import os, sys, subprocess, shutil, re, string, glob, tvdb_api, itertools, multiprocessing, ftplib

#No longer an instance method -- just a regular function.
#accepts an iterable and then splits it as [host,filename]
def upload_files(inpt):
    host=inpt[0]
    f=inpt[1]
    #host,f=inpt  #This might be a little cleaner, depending on your programming style.
    host.storbinary(('STOR /'+f.split('/')[-1]), open(f, 'rb'))

files = [os.path.join(r, f) for r, d, fs in os.walk(os.getcwd()) for f in fs if not f[0]=='.']
class FTP_Upload:
    def __init__(self, p=os.getcwd()):
        self.files_to_upload = sorted([f for f in files if os.path.split(f)[0] == p])
        self.target = raw_input("Enter the host you want to upload to: ")
        self.host = FTP('ftp.host1.com', 'user_name1', 'super_secret_password1') if self.target == 'host' else FTP('ftp.host2.com', 'user_name2', 'secret_password2') if self.target == 'host2' else None
    def multiupload(self):
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
        upload_this=[(self.host,f) for f in self.files_to_upload]
        p.map(upload_files,upload_this)
FTP_Upload().multiupload()
```

Hopefully that will work out for you.  Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, but when I remove that "(f)" from the multipupload, but now I get`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 315, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed

Comment: @RobinHood I've edited again.  As your traceback indicates, you can't pickle an instance method.  Change it to a regular function and hopefully you'll be all set.